# How can I invalidate the timer when timer going in Background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nstimer

In my app I used the timer,

When First time start the timer I want to stop that timer when it going in background,

So I used this code to stop the timer,

```
 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  FirstViewController *view = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
 [view.myticker invalidate];    //myticker is timer
    view.myticker = nil;
 [view release];
}
```

I have invalidate the timer when Foreground delegate method call,

But when come to viewcontroller the old timer is still running,

How can i invalidate the timer when timer going in Background?

Comment: quick check: make sure your view.myticker isn't nil with an NSLog check in your applicationWillEnterForeground method before you try to invalidate it

Comment: I have already checked that When it came in background Timer is not nil.After that i try to nil a Timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to move your timer to your delegate, in fact that is quite a bad idea as it has no purpose being there!

You should observe the following notifications (depending on OS version, the latter being in OS4+)...

`UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` 
`UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`

Observe these from within your view controller and invalidate the timer. There are corresponding notifications when the app starts again...

`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`
`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `NSTimer` variable in `AppDelegate` method and synthesize it. Then using `sharedApplication` of AppDelegate, use that variable in whole project and do not create any new variable. Also perform `invalidate` method on the same instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

In one global file create a time.

In app delegate method,

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSTimer *t ;
    if ([t isValid]) {
        [t invalidate];
    }

}
```

use above code shall help you to stop timer when application goes into background.